# Display current category title on category page

Tags: php, categories, genesis-theme-framework

Using the following code in a category template, but instead of showing the current category page that I am on, it displays the first category of the first post. For example on Food category page it should say Food, but instead it says Desserts because the first post's category is desserts. Here is the site http://theveganproject.ca/wp/category/food/

```
add_action ( 'genesis_before_content', 'sk_show_category_name' );
function sk_show_category_name() {
$category = get_the_category();
if (is_category()) {
    echo '<div id="cat-name">' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</div>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

On a category page, you can use the function [`single_cat_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title), or the more generic [`single_term_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_term_title). These functions pull from the global `$wp_query` object, via [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object).

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `single_cat_title('' , true )` this function and add those parameters to removed the prefix.